# Laravel's Artisan Can't Connect to Database, Throws Error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]"

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have the following migration:

```
<?php

class Create_Users_Table {

    /**
     * Make changes to the database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Revert the changes to the database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate`, I get the following error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively  (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3306) in C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\database\connectors\mysql.php on line 33

Call Stack:
    0.0007     326008   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\artisan:0
    0.0312    1527392   2. require('C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\artisan.php') C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\artisan:24
    0.0414    2067048   3. Laravel\CLI\Command::run() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\artisan.php:42
    0.0448    2171864   4. Laravel\CLI\Tasks\Migrate\Migrator->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\command.php:49
    0.0448    2171864   5. Laravel\CLI\Tasks\Migrate\Migrator->migrate() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\tasks\migrate\migrator.php:52
    0.0448    2171928   6. Laravel\CLI\Tasks\Migrate\Resolver->outstanding() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\tasks\migrate\migrator.php:69
    0.0448    2172368   7. Laravel\CLI\Tasks\Migrate\Database->ran() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\tasks\migrate\resolver.php:53
    0.0448    2172368   8. Laravel\CLI\Tasks\Migrate\Database->table() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\tasks\migrate\database.php:61
    0.0454    2209248   9. Laravel\Database::connection() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\cli\tasks\migrate\database.php:81
    0.0471    2287344  10. Laravel\Database::connect() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\database.php:52
    0.0482    2302840  11. Laravel\Database\Connectors\MySQL->connect() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\database.php:66
    0.0482    2305032  12. PDO->__construct() C:\xampp\htdocs\snip\laravel\database\connectors\mysql.php:33

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I am on Win7 and XAMPP running PHP 5.4. Is there something I am missing?

Edit: Here are the DB config inside database.php:

```
'connections' => array(

        ...

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'   => 'mysql',
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'database' => 'makeitsnappy',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
...
)
```

Also, the target machine is my local server and I have full control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is troubles with DB config. Check your dsn string or hostname and db driver type.

Comment: The service you try to connect to is not running of running at another address of at another port of a firewall is active

Comment: DB config is okay. I can confirm this because when I ran `php artisan migrate:install`, the laravel migration table was installed correctly, using the same DB settings.

Comment: Provide more information.
What is the target machine? What config params do you use for connection? Do you have control over the target machine, etc.

Comment: You can restart you mysql server.